Slack new line in the numbered list
How would I insert a new line in Slack when using numbered lists?
What I need:
1. First paragraph.<br>
   New lined text in the first paragraph.
2. Second paragraph.

When I hit Enter/Shift-Enter/Option-Enter - it inserts a new line but increases numbering, which is not what I want.
Also, I tried to use tabs, but it appeared that the Tab key navigates to the 'Send now' button.
